# Show that x(t) is bounded by |x(t)|≤ 2A/βb

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, mathematical-physics, boundary-value-problem, oscillatory-integral

Assume that the system is underdamped, starts from rest, and the force is bounded (|f(t)| < A for all t).
Given the formula for the oscillator:
$$ x(t)= \frac{1}{\beta m}\int_{0}^{t}f(t-v)e^{-b/2m}sin\beta v dv. $$
Where $$ \beta = \frac{1}{2m}\sqrt{4mk-b^{2}} $$
Show that  $$ \left | x(t) \right | \leq \frac{2A}{\beta b} $$

Obviously, we need to manipulate the expressions inside the integral to reduce to x(t) to the desired fraction. I know that we could simplify f(t-v) inside the integral to A since |f(t)| < A for all t. Beyond that, I'm not sure what the next steps are.

Comment: Did you try taking the absolute value of both sides and using $$\bigg \lvert \int g d \mu \ \bigg \rvert \le \int \lvert g \rvert d \mu$$ and then note that $\lvert f \rvert \le A, \lvert \sin(\cdot) \rvert \le 1$? Also, are you sure the form of the exponential in the integral is correct?

Comment: Yes, the exponential in the integral is correct.  Once you apply that | f | < A and | sin ( * )| <= 1, I'm unsure what next steps to go from there. It seems impossible for the exponential to reduce to what we need to.

Comment: Additionally, we are given the original oscillator equation mx''(t) + bx'(t) + kx(t) = f(t) where f(t) is the external force